# Facebook like this counter?

Tags: facebook, sdk

i like to know how this is made?
https://www.facebook.com/AnttilaNetAnttila?sk=app_151432998287071

So it counts like this pages likers and out put it in the iframe.
Any succession?

Answer (score 1):

The iframe app simply fetch the Open Graph of the page ( in this case http://graph.facebook.com/AnttilaNetAnttila) and display the likes count.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the likes using jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/j777f/

Comment: Hi how i can visuals that in html and css? inside div?